# Will installing the CCCP make any difference in MKV handling in Win7/WMP12?

Tags: windows-7, video, thumbnails, matroska, windows-media-player

I've found out that MKV files play just fine on WMP12 (Win 7 64-bit). However, in Windows Explorer, no thumbnails for such files are there and in the information panel at the bottom, no information about the length of the video is shown.

I wonder if installing [CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/wiki/index.php?title=FAQ) would fix these 2 issues and/or improve the playability of MKV even further.

If not, what else can I do to fix them?

Comment: I've actually tried CCCP, and it did nothing. Now I don't care about thumbnails or video info, but I would like at least to be able to view MKV's embedded subtitles in WMP. Shark007's pack could do it, but I don't need a whole pack, just the filter or codec that would enable subtitles in WMP. 

Any ideas?

Comment: Update: I installed DirectVobSub, and the subtitles appeared! But, I'm not able to locate the Configure screen to decrease the size of the font. Can't find it in the program folder or anywhere. The installer just installs VSfilter.dll and uninstall.exe. Any ideas?

Comment: When you play a movie with subtitles, an icon in the tray should appear.

Comment: I would like to add that ffdshow now supports subtitles quite nicely. Since I use ffdshow, I don't require directvobsub separately anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the Klite codec pack. It should solve all your problems.

PS Am I too late?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using a codec pack - they tend to just overwrite existing codecs, which might trigger undesired side effects down the road.

I reckon you're better off installing the DirectShow filters from [ffdshow tryouts](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/), if you haven't already. For MKV handling, you'll also need [Haali Media Splitter](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/), which integrates neatly into ffdshow. You won't need to do anything besides installing and maybe deselecting some stuff you don't want (although the preselections are quite good), and MKVs will just work in WMP and WMC.